# Access config values in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently introduced https://www.npmjs.com/package/config to handle my config:

```
...
config/
    dev.json
    uat.json
    production.json
package.json
```

In `dev.json` I have something like:

```
{
    "someVar": "something"
}
```

I used to be able to access config values in `package.json` like:

```
"scripts": {
    "some_command": "do_something $npm_package_config_someVar"
}
```

But now this doesn't work - those variables are empty.

How can I access values from `config/dev.json` in `packages.json`?

Edit: using `$npm_config_someVar` is also empty

Answer (score 0):

```
var pkg = require('./package.json');
console.log(pkg.name);
```

Comment: Question is about reading config in package.json, not from package.json

Comment: The `name` is one of attributes defined in **package.json**, LOL